# hibernate cache using scheduler in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My Application has 10-12 dashboards which have components that refresh data every 50 seconds, and this application used by nearly ~5000 people, at peak time its giving too much spike on DB server which leads hang of the server and haywire.

And I am using Spring data jpa + hibernate, and all of those queries are `native` queries.

To reduce the DB server, I came to the conclusion that some scheduler will read the data for dashboards from the DB and write to a file and front end will read it from that file, writing thread will keep updating it for every 50 seconds and reading thread will read every 60 seconds, we assume this way at least will avoid one dashboard query will be fired for more than one user only once.

will that above theory work in prod ? or can I get any help from `hibernate cache` or any other way to tackle these kind of issues.

I can't do stored procedures because its still effects the DB server, this server is being used for so many other applications as well.

Comment: You Don't need to do such thing if you enable hibernate second level cache and hibernate query cache

Comment: @Spara but I am using `Native Queries`  which means hibernate will invalidate `cache`